# Are electron spin axis and magnetic moment axis fully aligned?

Tags: electrons, quantum-spin, magnetic-moment

It is known that the electrons behave in magn. moment detectors experiments at 45 degrees non classically but quantum mechanically where the amount of spin up and spin down electrons in percentage is 85% to 15% instead 75% to 25%. Can this be explained by describing the electron spin axis and magnetic axis not being fully aligned but the real  magnetic pole is describing a circle around the spin axis so making the net magnetic moment aligned with the spin even though the real magn. axis is preccessing. In that case the angle between them can be calculated regarding the experimental results that give these 85% to 15%?

Comment: Can you include a reference for your data?

Comment: https://youtu.be/v657Ylwh-_k     watch at 18:42